# id not defined on laravel controller

Tags: mysql, laravel, controller

I have 2 section called Vendor and Vendor Contact. So when I show vendor details, it can create/add new contacts. I've called vendor id on VendorDetail.blade.php like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ven_id" value="{{$vendor->id}}">
```

then I put this url on my create_contact button:

```
<a href="{{ url('system/procurement/vendor-contact/create') }}" id="add-contact" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mb-4"><i class="simple-icon-plus"></i> Add New Contact</a>
```

and this is my ContactController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Home\Procurement;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Model\Vendors;
use App\Model\ContactPerson;
use App\Model\ItemCategory;
use App\Model\CategoryVendor;
use App\Model\Status;
use App\Model\VendorDocument;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      return view('home.vendor.contact.add',compact('vendor'));
    }

    public function create(Request $request)
    {
      $vendor_id = $request->ven_id;
      $vendor = Vendors::find($vendor_id);
      return $vendor;
      return view('home.vendor.contact.add',compact('vendor'));
    }
}
```

and this is what i wrote on my routes:

```
Route::resource('vendor-contact', 'Home\Procurement\ContactController');
```

but it always return 404|not found, which means the controller cannot read the vendor_id. is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: you don't return anything while you're making a compact

Comment: Remove `return $vendor;`

Comment: `<a href...` won't submit your form and thus your `input type="hidden"` is never sent with the request

Comment: "_but it always return 404|not found, which means the controller cannot read the vendor_id_" I'd say no, it does not mean that. It means the route has not been found. Can you post the route?

Comment: You won't get hidden inputs on your form request. Please set that input as disable using ajax instead of type='hidden' in the input.

Comment: I've already add my routes above thank for remind me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass id with `href` like below:

```
<a href="{{ url('system/procurement/vendor-contact/create/'.$vendor->id) }}" id="add-contact" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mb-4"><i class="simple-icon-plus"></i> Add New Contact</a>
```

And your route should be:

```
Route::any('vendor-contact/create/{id}', 'Home\Procurement\ContactController@create')
Route::resource('vendor-contact', 'Home\Procurement\ContactController')->except('create');
```

And then controller:

```
public function create($id)
{      
  $vendor = Vendors::find($id);     
  return view('home.vendor.contact.add',compact('vendor'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this code

`<a href="{{ url('system/procurement/vendor-contact/create') }}" id="add-contact" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary mb-4"><i class="simple-icon-plus"></i> Add New Contact</a>`

process with vuejs/ajax/js or something ? or there is  a Form between ?

You shoud check your route and do `dd($request->all());`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $vendor = Vendors::find($vendor_id);
```

function model::find something have problems.cause if it doesnt found a entity return 404, try it

```
$vendor=Vendors::where('id',$vendor_id)->first();
```

Comment: "_function model::find something have problems_" Says who?

Comment: Soo I mean, sometimes it is thought that it is an error but it does not find an entity